# Post order traverse in scheme

Tags: algorithm, tree, scheme, r5rs, postorder

I'm working on post order traversal to a binary search tree. This is what I have so far

```
(define (head tree)
    (car tree))
(define (left tree)
    (cadr tree))
(define (right tree)
    (caddr tree))

    (define (post-order node)  
     (if (null? node)
           '()
            (append (cons (post-order (left node))
            (post-order (right node)))
            (head node))))
```

I expect this code can return a list of post order traverse. However it doesn't even compile.
The error is

```
mcar: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: 5
```

I have checked the syntax of append and cons. And I still can't figure out this problem. It seems like there is something wrong with the logic rather than syntax.

Can you point it out and explain it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `append` the arguments are lists. In your code you are adding the `head` as the dotted value and thus this list can only ble the last argument in consecutive `append`. This would fix it:

```
(define (post-order node)  
  (if (null? node)
      '()
      (append (post-order (left node))
              (post-order (right node))
              (list (head node)))))
```